# WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'X' in output.globals – guessing 'X'

Tags: angular, rollupjs, ng-packagr, umd

```
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'moment' in output.globals – guessing 'momentImported'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'odata-parser' in output.globals – guessing 'parser'
```

I receive this message when I try to bundle my library to Universal Module Definition. The warning can be fixed by adding umdModuleIds in ng-package.json.

The [documentation](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md#resolving-umd-module-identifiers) gives us the following explanation:

> When writing the UMD bundle, ng-packagr does its best to provide
>   common default values for the UMD module identifiers. Also, rollup
>   will do its best to guess the module ID of an external dependency.
>   Even then, **you should make sure that the UMD module identifiers of the
>   external dependencies are correct**. In case ng-packagr doesn't provide
>   a default and rollup is unable to guess the correct identifier, you
>   should explicitly provide the module identifier by using umdModuleIds
>   in the library's package file section like so: ...

`umdModuleIds`:

> A map of external dependencies and their correspondent UMD module
>   identifiers. Map keys are TypeScript / EcmaScript module identifiers.
>   Map values are UMD module ids. The purpose of this map is to correctly
>   bundle an UMD module file (with `rollup`). By default, `rxjs`, `tslib`
>   and `@angular/*` dependency symbols are supported.

How can I find or check for correctness the UMD ID of moment, odata-parser or any other module that must be added to the umdModuleIds?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the docs hard to understand, too. The ng-packagr `umdModuleIds` setting in `ng-package.json` is a mapping of import names to module IDs that UMD registers in the javascript `global` object.

By import name I mean, in your typescript code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

The string `moment` should be the key under `umdModuleIds`.

The value should match up with the global variable registered in the UMD bundle for the package. If you take a look in the JS file you're importing, you'll see the `global.X` value being set. For [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js) the code block is:

```js
//! moment.js

;(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.moment = factory()
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';
```

The line `global.moment = ...` gives you what you need. So, to import moment correctly, your `ng-package.json` should include:

```
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "moment": "moment"
    }
  }
```

In this case, it turns out that ng-packagr's guess is correct - the import name matches the UMD global variable, but you need to specify it explicitly for ng-packagr to know for sure.

There should be another (and better) way that you can fix this for NPM dependencies, which is to add the library dependencies to the library `package.json` file (the package.json in the same dir as the ng-package.json file). I would try that first - I believe ng-packagr correctly finds the UMD module ids when the dependency is included in the package.json.

However, in the case that you're using local libraries (libraries in the same angular workspace), or libraries which otherwise can't be analyzed by ng-packagr, it's necessary to look at the UMD ids and make sure they match up. For example, if you're using scoped/namespaced names for your internal libs, like `@mycompany/util`, you'll see that the UMD module IDs are registered like this:

`File: ~/dist/util/bundles/mycompany-util.umd.js`

```js
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define('@mycompany/util', ['exports'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory((global.mycompany = global.mycompany || {}, global.mycompany.util = {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

so given the line `global.mycompany.util =` you'll need to specify UMD module IDs like:

```
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "@mycompany/util": "mycompany.util"
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Could you cover the case in which one has `@mycompany/product-name/ui-module-name` as I've tried `"@mycompany/product-name/ui-module-name": "mycompany['product-name']['ui-module-name']` to no avail, with the warning being `No name was provided for external module '@mycompany/product-name/ui-module-name' in output.globals – guessing 'uiModuleName'`

Comment: Did you try looking at the first few lines of the @mycompany/product-name/ui-module-name umd.js file? You just need to match that in the dependee library's ng-package.json.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately it was as I posted `"mycompany['product-name']['ui-module-name']"`

Comment: That's equivalent to `mycompany.product-name.ui-module-name` - try that.

Comment: Unfortunately no good either. It _guesses_ `uiModuleName` but nothing I've tried has worked as yet

Comment: Perhaps there's something missing in a `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Updating angular to the v13 removed automatically `umdModuleIds` so I do think we shouldn't use it anymore

Comment: I agree @RaphaëlBalet - Angular 13 and up no longer build UMD output in Angular Package Format (https://angular.io/guide/angular-package-format), so this question and answer are irrelevant for ng 13+. However it's still relevant for older code.