# How to put an entry for angular-redux/store in an angular library's umdModuleIds

Tags: angular, redux, ng-build, umd, angular-redux

I'm trying to create a library that depends on @angular-redux/store but I can't figure out how to put an entry for it at my angular library's umdModuleIds in ng-package.json:

```
"umdModuleIds": {
  "redux": "Redux",
  "@angular-redux/store": "???" // anybody knows what's the correct entry?
}
```

I've already checked the @angular-redux/store's UMD file but the entry it has doesn't work. This one doesn't either but works well in webpack externals:

window["angular-redux"].store

Comment: This would be the official answer from ng-packagr:
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/dependencies.md#resolving-umd-module-identifiers 

Still I'm not entirely sure what the correct way would be here... Seams like you can take what ever value you want, but just make sure, it's consistent across libraries?
Or what's your take?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402807/warning-no-name-was-provided-for-external-module-x-in-output-globals-guessi
check the accepted answer, that will shed some light into this :)